# Rotating faces Rubik's Cube C#

Tags: c#, rotation, unity-game-engine, rubiks-cube

I've been looking around the internet for a few days now, and I can't really find an answer that i can understand well enough to rotate my Rubik's Cube.

I have made my own 3D Model using Blender of a Rubik's Cube and imported it in to Unity which is what I'm going to use to rotate the faces.

But I just don't seem to understand the mathematics involved in rotating a Rubik's Cube, should i use Matrices? If so how do i couple it all together for it to work?

I can rotate a single side around by grouping the bricks together by faces, but the moment you turn the next face it would completely disrupt the other one.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `but the moment you turn the next face it would completely disrupt the other one` - Isn't this exactly what makes solving a Rubik's Cube so hard?

Comment: Nope, no college assignment. I'm studying on my own.
@Bobson I'm sorry if it was unclear, i meant that it would destroy the "GameObject face".. i know how a rubiks cube works :P

Comment: @balls - Ah, that makes sense now.

Comment: hi @Nicholas - would you mind "Tick"ing this old QA you started?  thanks.

Comment: @JoeBlow Hi - I don't mind at all, however I was hoping for more answers but they never came - I guess the only one here will do. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My idea: Keep each of the 26 blocks as separate `GameObject` objects (8 corners, 12 edges, 6 centers), with each block's origin in the center of the cube. Separately you keep track of which block is currently where on the cube, for example in a 3D array.

Then when a face needs to be turned:

- Find out which blocks belong to the face.
- Rotate each of those blocks around the axis of rotation (through the middle of the cube) using Unity's normal rotation functionality.
- Update the information on which blocks are where.