# Rotating the planes of a Rubik's cube in Unity

Tags: c#, vector, unity-game-engine, rotation

I'm trying to rotate the planes of a Rubik's cube using RotateAround, my problem is in determining the axis vector that a certain plane needs to rotate around, I'll always need to use the vector that passes through the center gameobject but using Vector3.up/ down/ right/left is useless especially if the cube rotates and changes position, any suggestions? :\

for instance, this is the line I use to rotate the green plane, green is the center gameobject in this case

```
    Parent.transform.RotateAround(green.transform.position,WHAT AXIS VECTOR?,100*Time.deltaTime);
```

Comment: hi msLangdon, just FYI, I can warn you, this is *extremely* difficult to do well.  it is not a job for a beginner or learner programmer.  one basic tip, note that Transform.Rotate can work **in local axis** (read the doco).  that may help you.  it's alway "local up" if you see what I mean.

Comment: well I'm not a beginner in programming and math in general, I'm kinda new to unity :\ is it that hard? :\

Comment: ok, in the first instance master the difference between local and world axes, enjoy

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rotating faces Rubik's Cube C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15572326/rotating-faces-rubiks-cube-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is the following:

On positions of each of 6 central pieces on every side I would place an empty game object. I would rotate them manually so that they all have their local Y axis pointing outward from the surface (switch to local space in Unity for this).

Now, whenever I would need a rotation of a side I would:

- parent all 9 pieces of the side under my empty game object for THAT side
- rotate the parent game object 90 or -90 degrees around local Y axis
- un-parent all 9 pieces (so that they are ready for next cycle)

All you'd need is to check these out from [Unity Docs](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/): transform.parent, transform.localEulerAngles and some rotation functions, probably Mathf.Lerp and Vector3.Lerp for smooth rotations.

Comment: this is quite correct.  *unfortunately*, totally setting aside "just" the hassles of moving stuff around like that in Unity; the whole thing's almost impossible unless you follow an mvc pattern and you have a data structure that understands all the pieces moving around.  it's a real pain!

Comment: it is a real pain indeed :| but thanks I'm still trying